# Is a ReadWriteLock used to prevent an exception? Which one?

Tags: java, multithreading, io

I am concurrently reading / writing to one file from multiple threads with no synchronization of the *Reader* and *Writer*. Yet no exceptions are being thrown.

Is a *ReadWriteLock* used to prevent exceptions?

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int nmbOfThreads = 10;
        int nmbOfReadWritePerThread = 100;
        int maxWaitTimeBetweenReadWrite = 3; // seconds
        try {
            File f = new File("C:\\tmp\\foo.txt");
            Writer wrtr = new FileWriter(f);
            Reader rdr = new FileReader(f);

            Set<Thread> threads = new HashSet();        
            for(int i = 0; i < nmbOfThreads; i++) {                
                Thread t = new Thread(new Worker(rdr, wrtr, nmbOfRdWrtPerThread, maxWaitTimeBetweenReadWrite));                
                threads.add(t);
            }

            for(Thread t : threads) { t.start(); }     
            for(Thread t : threads) { t.join(); }        
            wrtr.close();    
            rdr.close();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    static void rndmPause(int range) throws Exception {
        long milliSec = (long) new Random(System.currentTimeMillis()).nextLong();
        milliSec = (long) (Math.abs(milliSec) % (range * 1000));
        Thread.sleep((long) milliSec);
    }


         static class Worker implements Runnable {
             Reader rdr; Writer wrtr;
             int nmbRdWrt, maxWaitTime;

             public Worker(Reader rdr, Writer wrtr, int nmbRdWrt, int maxWaitTime) {
                 this.rdr = rdr;
                 this.wrtr = wrtr;
                 this.nmbRdWrt = nmbRdWrt;
                 this.maxWaitTime = maxWaitTime;
             }

             public void run() {
                 try {
                     for(int i = 0; i < nmbRdWrt; i++) {
                         rndmPause(maxWaitTime);
                         wrtr.write("foo" + System.getProperty("line.separator"));
                         wrtr.flush();

                         rndmPause(maxWaitTime);
                         char[] cbuf = new char[100];
                         rdr.read(cbuf);
                     }
                 } catch(Exception e) {
                     e.printStackTrace();
                 }      
             }                  
         }
     }
}
```

Or, is a *ReadWriteLock* only used to prevent multiple threads from stomping on each other and writing garbled text?

Comment: It is used to ensure correctness under concurrency.

Comment: @EJP I think I get it. The "ConcurrentModificationException" only happens in certain cases with Collections. In most cases, testing whether something is "ThreadSafe" is not easy!

Answer (score 0):

ReadWriteLock is not just used to prevent exceptions, it is to ensure that `writer` don't get access to write while any other `writer` or `reader` already is there. 
How do you deal with such situations?

Take a look

```
class Main {
    private static volatile int numFileWriter = 0;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int nmbOfThreads = 100;
        int nmbOfReadWritePerThread = 100;
        int maxWaitTimeBetweenReadWrite = 1; // seconds
        try {
            File f = new File("/home/mwalko/test");
            Writer wrtr = new FileWriter(f);
            Reader rdr = new FileReader(f);

            Set<Thread> threads = new HashSet();
            for(int i = 0; i < nmbOfThreads; i++) {
                Thread t = new Thread(new Worker(rdr, wrtr, nmbOfReadWritePerThread, maxWaitTimeBetweenReadWrite, i));
                threads.add(t);
            }

            for(Thread t : threads) { t.start(); }
            for(Thread t : threads) { t.join(); }
            wrtr.close();
            rdr.close();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    static void rndmPause(int range) throws Exception {
        long milliSec = (long) new Random(System.currentTimeMillis()).nextLong();
        milliSec = (long) (Math.abs(milliSec) % (range * 1000));
        Thread.sleep((long) milliSec);
    }


    static class Worker implements Runnable {
        Reader rdr; Writer wrtr;
        int nmbRdWrt, maxWaitTime, threadNumber;

        public Worker(Reader rdr, Writer wrtr, int nmbRdWrt, int maxWaitTime, int threadNumber) {
            this.rdr = rdr;
            this.wrtr = wrtr;
            this.nmbRdWrt = nmbRdWrt;
            this.maxWaitTime = maxWaitTime;
            this.threadNumber = threadNumber;
        }

        public void run() {
            try {
                for(int i = 0; i < nmbRdWrt; i++) {
                    rndmPause(maxWaitTime);
                    wrtr.write("foo thread: " + threadNumber + " num: " + numFileWriter + System.getProperty("line.separator"));
                    wrtr.flush();
                    numFileWriter++;
                    rndmPause(maxWaitTime);
                    char[] cbuf = new char[100];
                    rdr.read(cbuf);
                }
            } catch(Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

the result in file:

```
foo thread: 33 num: 0
foo thread: 99 num: 0
foo thread: 29 num: 0
foo thread: 39 num: 0
foo thread: 7 num: 0
foo thread: 98 num: 0
foo thread: 95 num: 0
foo thread: 20 num: 0
foo thread: 75 num: 0
foo thread: 58 num: 0
foo thread: 47 num: 0
foo thread: 67 num: 0
foo thread: 40 num: 0
foo thread: 37 num: 0
foo thread: 21 num: 0
foo thread: 74 num: 0
foo thread: 16 num: 0
foo thread: 0 num: 0
foo thread: 70 num: 0
foo thread: 73 num: 19
foo thread: 63 num: 19
foo thread: 38 num: 20
```

and when you synchronize it or use ReadWriteLock or use BufferedWriter(which is thread safe) the result can be correct. By correct I mean `numFileWriter` in good order

Comment: I actually WANT to throw an exception. How can I make my concurrently reading / writing to a file throw an exception?

Comment: You could call `tryLock()` on the lock and throw if it failed.

Comment: You said "of course it is preventing exceptions". Ok, what is the name of the exception?

Comment: @LouisWasserman I get it now. Other than modiifying an interating Collection, testing for thread safety is a huge challenge.